# Check null for HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I am making HTTP post request to REST service, When I get the HttpWebResponse back, I am doing below check. Should I also check responseStream != null when I am doing webresponse != null

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (webResponse != null)
{
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    int responseCode = (int)webResponse.StatusCode;
    if (responseStream != null && responseCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        cmsStoreWebResponse = ((new  StreamReader(responseStream)).ReadToEnd());`
    }
    else
    {
        this.LogError(string.Format("{0}\n Endpoint: {1}\n {2} {3} {4}", ErrorCodes.IWS_CMSRetrieve_ERROR_001, oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.IWS_CMSStore_ERROR_SERVICE_DOWN, responseStream, responseCode));
        serviceData.Fatal = true;
        serviceData.ErrorCode = ErrorCodes.IWS_EFORMSFORMSETS_001;
        serviceData.ErrorDetails = string.Format("\nEndpoint: {0}\n {1}", oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.RESPONSE_STREAM_NULL);
        throw new FaultException<ServiceExceptionData>(serviceData, new FaultReason(string.Format("\nEndpoint: {0}\n {1}", oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.RESPONSE_STREAM_NULL)));
    }
}
else
{
    this.LogError(string.Format("{0}\n Endpoint: {1}\n {2}",  ErrorCodes.IWS_CMSRetrieve_ERROR_001, oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.IWS_CMSStore_ERROR_SERVICE_DOWN));
    serviceData.Fatal = true;
    serviceData.ErrorCode = ErrorCodes.IWS_EFORMSFORMSETS_001;
    serviceData.ErrorDetails = string.Format("\nEndpoint: {0}\n {1}", oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.RESPONSE_STREAM_NULL);
    throw new FaultException<ServiceExceptionData>(serviceData, new FaultReason(string.Format("\nEndpoint: {0}\n {1}", oagEndpointUrl, ErrorCodes.RESPONSE_STREAM_NULL)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()` can return null, so yes, you should check whether it is null or not.

You should also check whether `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() == Stream.Null`

So, something like this:

```
var webResponseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

if (webResponseStream != null && webResponseStream != Stream.Null)
{
    //do stuff.
}
```

In case you're wondering, `webResponseStream != null` checks for whether a reference to a Stream has been assigned to the variable `webResponseStream`, whereas `webResponseStream != Stream.Null` checks whether or not the Stream instance assigned to `webResponseStream` contains any backing data.

Comment: Hi Brain, thank you for the response. What's the difference between webResponseStream != null and webResponseStream != Stream.Null

Comment: Hi @user3456546, I've updated my answer to reflect your follow-up question.

Comment: I have never seen anyone compare to `Stream.Null`. Can you show an example of comparing to it?

Comment: This answer is false. No built-in type can return null. What would that even mean compared to returning an empty stream?! The Stream.Null check is not sufficient to detect empty streams. It's not required to check for empty streams in the first place. => Don't check for null, Stream.Null or empty streams.

Comment: @usr Yup, you're absolutely correct. Unfortunately I'm not in the habit of revising old answers, or else I would have fixed this one a while ago.

Answer (score 11):

**No built-in type derived from `WebResponse`, in particular `HttpWebResponse`, can return null.** This superstitious belief has misled many developers. Don't check for null. Such code is dead code.

What would null even mean compared to returning an empty stream?! This does not make sense.

**Also, `GetResponse()` cannot return null.** Again, what is that supposed to mean?! The HTTP protocol does not support the notion of a "null response". If that ever happens due to a library bug it's not possible to handle that situation anyway. Any such check does not help.

It is possible to create classes derived from `WebResponse` that return an insane values such as `null`. No built-in class does that and it should be considered a bug to return `null`. Classes derived from `WebResponse` are very rare. I have never seen one.

Here's a good code pattern to use:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.org/");

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    var contents = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It demonstrates how to succinctly and safely read the contents of an HTTP URL using `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: ReSharper warns about it being “possibly null” still, in 2021. *sigh*

Comment: That said, this shows another failure of using HttpWebRequest / streams over HTTP: not honoring the CharacterSet of the response.. Windows-1252 with “è” would be garbled :-/ Still a thing in 2021.. for reasons..